# php como saber de que tipo de objeto es la var

Tags: php, poo

estoy haciendo una función de mi clase **UsuarioHandler.php** y se llama **insertar**:

```
public function insertar($usuario){
    echo gettype($usuario);
}
```

Lo que quería hacer antes de llevar a cabo la **inserción** es asegurarme de que el objeto  es de **tipo Usuario**.

He estado haciendo la siguiente prueba :

```
$uh = new UsuarioHandler();

$var = new Usuario(
  0, "jose", "apellidos", "jose@gmail.com", "password",
  "españa", '1434-04-03', '2000-01-01'
);
$uh->insertar($var);
$uh->insertar($var);
```

**¿Que ocurre?** pues que la función **insertar()** me devuelve: `object`.
Esta bien, pero quiero que me devuelva, por ejemplo, un string del nombre del tipo de la clase, es decir, algo así: `"Usuario"` para poder hacer un **if** y comprobar si es  igual a el tipo que se le debe pasar. Temas de seguridad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Así puedes conocer el nombre de la clase, espero te sirva:

```
 echo "El nombre de la clase es: " , get_class($var) , "\n";
```

> Si tienes mas dudas sobre esto te puede servir :
>   https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-class.php

Comment: la variable bar esta en la pregunta del compañero

Comment: @JackNavaRow no creo que sea una discusión relevante.

Comment: @JackNavaRow he pasado un ejemplo, efectivamente se puede poner solamente echo get_class($var) para saber la clase

Answer (score 1):

En php5.5 y adelante puedes utilizar  la propiedad `class` que tienen todos los objetos:

`echo $usuario::class`

Esto te devuelve el fqcn de dicha clase, lo que sería el namespace y la clase correspondiente. Esto te será más útil si en tu proyecto tienes varios spacenames y varias clases usuario

Comment: de hecho viene desde la [version 5.5](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-class.php#115849)

Comment: Cierto. Lo cambio ahora mismo ( las prisas y escribir siempre 7.0 )

Answer (score 0):

Otra posibilidad es mediante la funcion [is_a()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-a.php).

Esta función comprueba si el objeto dado por `object` es de dicha clase.

```
$var = new Usuario(
      0, "jose", "apellidos", "jose@gmail.com", "password",
      "españa", '1434-04-03', '2000-01-01'
    );

is_a($var, 'Usuario');
```

Un ejemplo aplicado a tu código:

```
$uh = new UsuarioHandler();

$var = new Usuario(
  0, "jose", "apellidos", "jose@gmail.com", "password",
  "españa", '1434-04-03', '2000-01-01'
);

if (is_a($var, 'Usuario')) {
    echo "Es de la clase Usuario ";
    $uh->insertar($var);
}
```

Comprobamos que la variable `$var` pertenece a la clase `Usuario`, si es así, haremos las operaciones que correspondan.